# Referring the same element in underscore notation

Tags: scala

I have the following class definition and list

```
class myclass{
  val val1: Int = 1
  val val2: Int = 2
  ...
}
val mylist = List(a: myclass, b: myclass, c: myclass, d: myclass)
```

How can I convert the next line of code to underscore notation

```
mylist.foldLeft(0)((x,y) => x + y.val1 * y.val2)
```

I know that the next line doesn't work:

```
(0 /: mylist)(_ + _.val1 * _.val2)
```

This is because the first `_` is refered to `x` and the second is referred to `y`, but the third `_` scala doesn't know which variable is referred, my question is if there is a way that this works

Comment: What if there is no (sane) way to make it work with underscores? Maybe you could introduce a method `def prod12 = val1 * val2` on `myclass`, but that's it...

Comment: You could have a slightly more general solution to write `_ + _.let { x => x.val1 * x.val2 }`.

Comment: Why do you want to use underscore notation ?  - In general is better to name your parameters to make the code more readable, unless the function is very trivial _(which this is not the case)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez interestingly, the `_+_` is simple.

Comment: @som-snytt I must agree, the `_ + _` is one of the few cases on which underscore notation makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too crazy:

```
scala> case class C(v: Int, w: Int)
defined class C

scala> val cs = List(C(1,2),C(3,4))
cs: List[C] = List(C(1,2), C(3,4))

scala> cs.iterator.map(c => c.v*c.w).foldLeft(0)(_+_)
res0: Int = 14
```

It expresses that the operations are independent. Iterating avoids an intermediate list.

Comment: I would like to point out that this _"common"_ pattern of mapping and then folding with a natural `empty` value and `combine` function can be repleaced with the `foldMap` function of the **Foldable** _typeclass_ present on **Cats/Scalaz**, which also guarantees only one iteration.